# How to search in deep nested array?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to filter/search in a deeply nested array of subarrays
In order to explain my problem it is better to show the array structure first.

```
const arr = [
  [
    {
      title: "title 1",
      city: [
        {
          "0": "London"
        },
        {
          "1": "LA"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      title: "Title 2",
      city: [
        {
          "0": "New York"
        },
        {
          "1": "London"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      title: "Title 3",
      city: [
        {
          "0": "Paris"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      title: "title 4",
      city: [
        {
          "0": "London"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
];
```

As you see, in this nested Array there is a `city` array of of `key value pair objects` and my task is to search `value` in this `city` Array and return only first matching object of every subArray without flattening.

So, let's say the `filter keyword` is `London`, I want to return the first matching object of every subArray which inlcudes that `filter keyword`.
So here answer would be

```
const filteredArr = [
  [
    {
      title: "title 1",
      city: [
        {
          "0": "London"
        },
        {
          "1": "LA"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      title: "title 4",
      city: [
        {
          "0": "London"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
];
```

As you can see from first subArray only first object is returned, even though second object which has a `title 2` also includes a value of `London` in `city` array.

I know that I can get the first matching object with `find` method like this:

```
const filteredCity = city.find((obj) => Object.values(obj)[0] === "London");
```

But how to combine and get the desired array?

I am sorry if couldn't explain my Problem properly. Let me know if something is not clear.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the expected result for `Paris`? It is not clear what you want to happen when there is no match in a subarray. In my answer I seem to have interpreted this case differently than in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can first map the original array's subarrays and for each of them find the first object that has the city of choice. Then filter the mapped results to exclude the ones that didn't have a match:

```js
const arr = [[{title: "title 1",city: [{"0": "London"},{"1": "LA"}]},{title: "Title 2",city: [{"0": "New York"},{"1": "London"}]}],[{title: "Title 3",city: [{"0": "Paris"}]},{title: "title 4",city: [{"0": "London"}]}]];

const filteredArr = arr.map(sub =>
    sub.find(({city}) => city.some((obj) => Object.values(obj).includes("London")))
).filter(Boolean);

console.log(filteredArr);
```

Note that this result structure has one level of array removed, because in your desired result the second level array will **always** have exactly one element (since you wanted the first match only). An array that always has one element is overkill: you can just represent that with that element on its own without the needless wrapper.

If your really want that intermediate array, then chain a simple `.map`:

```js
const arr = [[{title: "title 1",city: [{"0": "London"},{"1": "LA"}]},{title: "Title 2",city: [{"0": "New York"},{"1": "London"}]}],[{title: "Title 3",city: [{"0": "Paris"}]},{title: "title 4",city: [{"0": "London"}]}]];

const filteredArr = arr.map(sub =>
    sub.find(({city}) => city.some((obj) => Object.values(obj).includes("London")))
).filter(Boolean).map(res => [res]);

console.log(filteredArr);
```

Answer (score 2):

First you need the flatten the array to make the nested array into a simple array. Then you can use loops to iterate through all items and when it finds the element then it simply returns the current parent object.

**It can find any matching keyword deeply nested in the array.**

```js
function searchArray(arr, keyword) {
    // Flatten the nested array into a single array of objects
    const flatArr = arr.flat(Infinity);

    // Search for the keyword in the flattened array
    const matchingObj = flatArr.find(obj => {
            // Check if any of the object's values contain the keyword
        for (let value of Object.values(obj)) {
            if (typeof value === 'object') {
                // If the value is an array of objects, search for the keyword in the objects' values
                for (let innerObj of value) {
                    if (Object.values(innerObj).some(val => val.includes(keyword))) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // If the value is a string, check if it contains the keyword
                if (value.includes(keyword)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    });

    return matchingObj || null;
}
```

This may be the solution you are looking for.

```js
const arr = [
    [
      {
        title: "title 1",
        city: [
          {
            "0": "London"
          },
          {
            "1": "LA"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        title: "Title 2",
        city: [
          {
            "0": "New York"
          },
          {
            "1": "London"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        title: "Title 3",
        city: [
          {
            "0": "Paris"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        title: "title 4",
        city: [
          {
            "0": "London"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
];
  
  
function searchArray(arr, keyword) {

if (keyword == '' || keyword == null || keyword == undefined || keyword == {}){
    return null;
}

// Flatten the nested array into a single array of objects
const flatArr = arr.flat(Infinity);

// Search for the keyword in the flattened array
const matchingObj = flatArr.find(obj => {
        // Check if any of the object's values contain the keyword
    for (let value of Object.values(obj)) {
        if (typeof value === 'object') {
            // If the value is an array of objects, search for the keyword in the objects' values
            for (let innerObj of value) {
                if (Object.values(innerObj).some(val => val.includes(keyword))) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        } else {
            // If the value is a string, check if it contains the keyword
            if (value.includes(keyword)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
});

return matchingObj || null;
}
  
console.log("Searching 'London'"); 
console.log(searchArray(arr, "London"));
console.log("Searching 'Title 3'"); 
console.log(searchArray(arr, 'Title 3'));
console.log("Searching invalid keyword");
console.log(searchArray(arr, "Hello"));
```